# Toggle method from different jQuery version

Tags: jquery, toggle

I know that this topic was already opened, but I think I have a different situation.

I need to do something like here:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/1/)

and that toggle function works like that only with jQuery 1.8.3 / 1.7.2 / 1.6.4 / 1.4.4, and I use 1.9.1, in which it doesn't work like that.

I am wondering if you can use multiple versions of jQuery on a single web page. Actually, I need one of those older versions of jQuery (1.8.3 / 1.7.2 / 1.6.4 / 1.4.4), just for

```
toggle()
```

method. Let's say 1.8.3.

I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) and I wan't to know if it's right:

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.8.3 -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var jQuery_1_8_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Here I have another question: I have to do the same thing for version 1.9.1? Because i will use just

```
jQuery_1_8_3('#selector').toggle();
```

The following code is required?

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.9.1 -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var jQuery_1_9_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

If it is, I will have to change all 1.9.1 function's selectors with

```
jQuery_1_9_1('#selector').function();
```

Comment: Why not just update your code instead of adding a new script just for `toggle()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery Migrate Plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) to resolve your issue over here.

Using the plugin is easy, just include it immediately after the script tag for jQuery, for example.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
```

For more information, see the [jQuery Migrate documentation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme).

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/1221/) *(Using the v1.9.1 & the migrate plugin)*

Comment: Can you show me how to restore the functionality of toggle from older versions with this jQuery Migrate Plugin?

I loaded the script:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-git.js"></script>

What I have to do now?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. Just call your function like `('#selector').toggle();`. That's it.